Can't paste commands into Ubuntu shell command line
I'm very new to Linux and coding in general, and I've been having an issue where I can't seem to properly paste code into my command line.
I can paste by right-clicking, but if the source I'm copying from has a command that spans multiple line spaces, it will paste the first line then think I'm pressing the "Enter" key, thus trying to run an incomplete command. I've seen similar threads where people say to press Ctrl + Shift + V, but this doesn't do anything in my case. Is there a way to paste a full command without having this issue? I use Linux Ubuntu shell for Windows. Any help is much appreciated :).

Please edit the question ans add the missing info. What version of Ubuntu? What is your setup that you are using Linux Ubuntu shell for Windows.  Also any other details that you have not mentioned.

The source of your copy/paste is incorrect. If a command spans multiple lines, each line should be terminated by a \ to indicate line continuation. You can add them to the source before copy/paste. Or you can set -o emacs  and open a temporary editor window by pressing Ctrl+x Ctrl+e at the bash command prompt. Then you can paste the multiple lines and edit. Stop editing with the write-and-exit command of the editor. You can choose which editor to use by setting the EDITOR environment variable, e.g. export EDITOR=vi. See also man bash.
